# PHP operator precedence bug?

Tags: php, parsing, compiler-construction, operators

The result of:

```
var_dump(null != $a = 15);
var_dump($a);
```

is:

```
bool(true)
int(15)
```

Why is this script not triggering an error?
Since `!=` (not equal operator) has a higher precedence than `=` (assignment operator), `$a` should be compared to `null` first?

Comment: definitely weird. `$a == null = 15` gives false dumps too. And putting in `(null != $a) = 15` does spit out an unexpected `=` error.

Comment: What alternative to interpreting it as `null != ($a=15)` is there? With `(null !=$a)=15` you'd try to assign the value 15 to a boolean value; that doesn't work.

Comment: @VolkerK this is an example, this script has no real life purpose! My reflection starts with this kind of expression that I see (and use) a lot `if (!$a = foo())`.

Comment: and then the same thing applies. How would you you assign a value to (!$a) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only reason I can find is that the documentation says that this is still legal: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php#example-129

It seems to be an exception to what is shown in the table above.

Comment: I think one other thing to note is the following comment on readability:
"Use of parentheses, even when not strictly necessary, can often increase readability of the code by making grouping explicit rather than relying on the implicit operator precedence and associativity."

Comment: It's not a "deliberate exception"; there is no addional lexer rule to explicitly "allow" this. It's just the normal way it works. The example in the manual is just a reminder for developers who wonder.

Comment: But it does seem to be an exception from the table at the top of the page, is it not? Even if there is no explicit rule in the parser/lexer, it seems to be an exception to the previous explanation.

Comment: @VolkerK Adjusted my wording, would you consider it more correct now?

Comment: Not really. There is no exception involved; it's merely something developers wonder about.

Comment: There is a rule of operator precedence, this expression clearly breaks the rule, this is called an exception. No big deal though, I'm moving on...

Answer (score 4):

This is not about operator precedence but about: operator precedence lists don't tell you the details (really, they never do), e.g. about the bison rules and the resulting pattern matching and stack reducing.
Let's take the statement `null != $a = 15;`, for simplicity without the var_dump.
This is how the parser "sees" this statement - or: sees that it *is* a statement.
(I hope this will be rendered with a fix-width font everywhere...)

```
null                       !=                    $a                                  =   15                           ;
                                                 T_VARIABLE                           
identifier                                       compound_variable                       T_LNUMBER
namespace_name                                   reference_variable                      common_scalar
general_constant                                 base_variable                           scalar
scalar                                           base_variable_with_functions_calls      expr_without_variable
expr_without_variable                            variable                            =   expr
expr                       T_IS_NOT_EQUAL             \______ expr_without_variable _________/
   \__________________    expr ____________________________________________/                                          ;
                           \_________________       unticked_statement _______________________________________________/
                                                     statement
```

( You can look up the rules at https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-5.6.15/Zend/zend_language_parser.y )

There's no special rule for the assignment operator in this case; there simply isn't another way for the parser to match the statement, so precedence doesn't apply.